# Why am I getting ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND after installing Semantic-UI?

Tags: javascript, html, css, semantic-ui, fomantic-ui

Basic html page. Just starting and downloading packages. Checking if my Semantic UI setup is properly installed, but when I open up my index.html page and check the console I get 'GET file:///semantic/dist/semantic.min.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND', along with 'GET file:///semantic/dist/semantic.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND'. Which is strange!

These are my script tags within my head tag inside my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>HTML5 boilerplate – all you really need…</title>
    <!-- You MUST include jQuery before Fomantic -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="/semantic/dist/semantic.min.css"
    />
    <script src="/semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body id="home">
    <h1>HTML5 boilerplate</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can click on the relative paths in both tags and it will take me to the actual file in my editor.

My current folder structure is:

> Semantic
>
> > dist
> >
> > > semantic.min.css
> > >
> > > semantic.min.js
>
> index.html

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ./semantic/dist/semantic.min.css

Comment: Bruh...

Thanks! Super appreciated.

Comment: No problem, that's what we are here for.